# Вывести только первые i-ые элементы из контейнера std::map

Tags: c++, циклы, вектор, контейнеры

Есть цикл, который выводит элементы из контейнера.
Как его модифицировать, что бы выводились не все элементы, а только до i-го.
На ум приходит только еще один цикл с прерыванием, но это не красиво.

```
int summ=0;
for (int n : itMap->second) {
         summ+=n;
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

Так не устроит?

```
summ = accumulate(itMap->second.begin(),next(itMap->second.begin(),i),0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно создать итератор и сдвинуть его

```
auto itMap = myMap.begin();///создаем итератор на начало 
auto itMap2 = myMap.begin();
advance(itMap2, k); //Сдвиг итератора
for (itMap = res.begin(); itMap != itMap2; itMap++){
действия
}
```